# How to delete records in mysql between databases

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following command to join records between two databases

```
select uat.users.fname,
rent.accounts.expires
from uat.users 
inner join rent.accounts 
on uat.users.fname=rent.accounts.account 
where rent.accounts.expires < '2015-07-03'
```

How would I delete all the records that the above command returns(from uat.users)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
delete uat.users
from uat.users 
inner join rent.accounts 
on uat.users.fname=rent.accounts.account 
where rent.accounts.expires < '2015-07-03'
```